# Git: After a three way merge, in what order are the commits displayed in git log?

Tags: git, git-merge

```
      A---B---C topic
     /         \
D---E---F---G---H master
```

Suppose this is my snapshot after doing a three way merge (H being the merge commit). Now if I run git log, what will be the order of commits that it displays?

Comment: Where is the "third" part of this merge?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I'm pretty sure the OP means a bog-standard merge (although it does not matter to `git log` here).

Comment: Isn't this how the three way merge is done? Using the three snapshots: common ancestor 'E' snapshot, snapshot pointed (at 'C') by branch 'topic' and snapshot pointed (at 'G') by branch 'master'. After merge, merge commit 'H' is created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Reverse chronological order](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_commit_ordering), unless you add various flags.  To make sure that children show up before parents, choose the commit or author date sort, or the topographic sort.

Comment: Let's assume in the diagram above, the more towards right the commit is, the more latest it is. So to confirm, the order here will be: H, C, G, B, F, A, E, D (from top to bottom)?

Comment: Yes.  One thing that's not clear from the documentation is whether this sort is done with the committer date or the author date: it's the committer date (again unless you specify options, which then enforce parent/child constraints as well, so there's no "author date but no other constraints" mode).

Comment: @nickie: it really depends on the committer date (and `git log` flags).  I'll give each commit a year (so that we only have to sort by one value, "the year"), and let's say that commit H is stamped 2014 for some reason even though it's 2016 now.  Meanwhile suppose C is stamped 2015, G is stamped 2014, B is stamped 2013, F is 2012, E is 2011, A is 2010, and D is 2009: the log output will show C, then H, then G, then B, then F, and so on.  If you add `--graph` the order will change: H will come out first, then C, B, A, then G, F, E, D.

Comment: On the other hand, if the dates are left-to-right as in the first comment above, you will see H first, then C,G,B,F... *unless* you add a topo-order constraint (such as `--graph` or `--topo-order`).  See the "commit ordering" section of the git log documentation.

Comment: @nickie: "rewritten" is the wrong word: the merge is itself a *new* commit, which gets a new pair of time-stamps as usual.  If the existing commits have dates from the future, or if the computer's clock is wrong, or if you force a particular date with environment variables (`GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE`) for instance, then we're back to the same old issue of `git log` sorting by commit dates.  If time moves sequentially, so that the new commit is newer than all existing commits, the merge will sort first.  And, you can force topo order (viewers that draw the graph usually do).

Comment: @nickie: I'll leave that to you, though if you snip yours out I'll snip out my replies, I guess. :-)